# Android button position changes while the screen rotating

Tags: android

1. Hai all I am new in android programming.....

   For my application I am using image button and it successfully
   installed on the device. But when I rotate the screen all the button
   position get changed...  and I need all the button placed at centre
   of the screen.... And here is my code....

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/testText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#FFCC99"
       android:textSize="24dp" />

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/up"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="124dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
       android:src="@drawable/up" />

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/left"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/up"
       android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="150dp"

       android:src="@drawable/left" />

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/right"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/up"
       android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
       android:src="@drawable/right" />

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/down"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/up"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="124dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
       android:src="@drawable/down" />
   ```

   Please help............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:gravity` to `center`.
The following layout will do for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cool Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There are other ways to do it.
1. Using relative layout
2. Using 2 layouts : 1 one for portrait and and 1 for landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your widgets in a single container (LinearLayout) and center it. For that you can use the gravity attribute.

You can check this page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications to your code. Please check whether this is the desired one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Sample text"
    android:textColor="#FFCC99"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/up" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/down" />

</LinearLayout>
```